# org.glassfish.json.JsonObjectBuilderImpl$JsonObjectImpl cannot be cast to javax.json.JsonArray

Tags: java, json

I am using Netbeans to develop my program, a ejb targetting JEE7 glassfish 5.1. It involves json parsing. As usual, I use an independent client to test my coding before I port it to glassfish. The problem is the independent client works while the ejb hits "org.glassfish.json.JsonObjectBuilderImpl$JsonObjectImpl cannot be cast to javax.json.JsonArray".

Here is my coding, same in both client and ejb:

```
JsonReader rdr = Json.createReader(new StringReader(strJson));
JsonObject obj = rdr.readObject();
JsonObject hp = obj.getJsonObject("HistoricalScore");
JsonArray scores = hp.getJsonArray("Score");
....
```

The independent client works well but the ejb hits the exception at the last statement.

Here is the json:

```
{
"HistoricalScore":{
  "GameCode":{"abFundCode":"K44992"},
  "Score":[
    {"PerformanceId":"0P0001HFQH",
     "Score":103.45,
     "LastUpdate":"02-06-2023",
     "ScoreDiv":130.60727,
     "ScoreType":1,
     "CloseScore":103.45,
     "SessionId":99,
     "EffectiveDate":"01-06-2023"},
    {......}
  ]
}
```

Both client and ejb are compiled with `Java_EE_from_Glassfish_5 - jakarta.json.jar` in the library and I didn't (unless I miss it) find any other json.jar in the library list.

Client runs within Netbeans and ejb also runs in glassfish deployed from Netbeans. Netbeans has java env pointing to jre of jdk1.8.0_202 and glassfish also has `AS_JAVA` parm pointing to the same.

Any help is much appreciated. Also, is there a way to find out where does `JsonObjectBuilderImpl` come from at runtime?

Edit:
Here is the full stack trace:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.glassfish.json.JsonObjectBuilderImpl$JsonObjectImpl cannot be cast to javax.json.JsonArray
at org.glassfish.json.JsonObjectBuilderImpl$JsonObjectImpl.getJsonArray(JsonObjectBuilderImpl.java:213)
at whale.util.UTrustHASE.update(UTrustHASE.java:99)
at whale.data.CaptureUTrust.run(CaptureUTrust.java:86)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1057)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1129)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4796)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:632)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:584)
at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:72)
at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:859)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:799)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:584)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:139)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:116)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor71.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:859)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:799)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:345)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4768)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4756)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBObjectInvocationHandler.java:181)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:55)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy258.run(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.privateInvoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:199)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:110)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.codegen.CodegenStubBase.invoke(CodegenStubBase.java:196)
at whale.data.__CaptureUTrustRemote_Remote_DynamicStub.run(whale/data/__CaptureUTrustRemote_Remote_DynamicStub.java)
at whale.data._CaptureUTrustRemote_Wrapper.run(whale/data/_CaptureUTrustRemote_Wrapper.java)
at whale.util.JobScheduleBean.activateService(JobScheduleBean.java:202)
at whale.util.JobScheduleBean.runTimer(JobScheduleBean.java:132)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1057)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1129)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4796)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:632)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:584)
at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:81)
at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:859)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:799)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:584)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:139)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundTimeout(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:121)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:859)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:799)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:345)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4768)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4756)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.callEJBTimeout(BaseContainer.java:4061)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBTimerService.deliverTimeout(EJBTimerService.java:1176)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBTimerService.access$000(EJBTimerService.java:65)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBTimerService$TaskExpiredWork.run(EJBTimerService.java:1895)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the full stack trace of the exception.